# pandas.to_datetime year containing last two digits

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm working with pandas using python, and a the csv file I got has the datetime in the following format:

```
03-31-17 22:15:00
```

The year is using the last two digits. How can I use `pandas.date_time` with that nomenclature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `parse_dates=[0]` parameter in [**`pd.read_csv`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) where `0` is the column the dates are in.  Pandas will handle the format just fine.

```
txt = "03-31-17 22:15:00"

pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), header=None, parse_dates=[0])

                    0
0 2017-03-31 22:15:00
```

Comment: If you answer any faster you are liable to get some sort of injury.

Comment: @StephenRauch I'm seeing a dr tomorrow

Comment: That doesn't answer the title of the question

Comment: @agemO The question was about the last two digits.  I recognized that the reason the last two digits persisted past parsing was because they were kept as strings.  If they were converted to `datetime`, Pandas would present them in more abbreviated fashion if appropriate.  I provided a means to parse them as dates at the point of initial parsing.  That, in turn, took care of those pesky last two digits.

Comment: I didn't want to say that your answer is a bad one, it is even the most correct answer for the body of the question. I posted this comment because at that time I was just genuinely hoping for someone to answer the title of the question.

Comment: No worries, I didn't take it that way.  But it was a fair question, so I responded to your comment the best I could. (-:

Answer (score 2):

Use a lowercase 'y' instead of a uppercase one:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='...%y...')
```